# Random Walk stops at n-th node

Tags: probability

Considering the following random walk problem: There are $n(n\in N, n\ge 4)$ points on a straight
line. A drunk man starts at the second point and for each step, the probability that he steps forward
and backward are both $0.5$, and he can only go to adjacent points each time. If he ever reaches the first
point or the $n$-th point, he stops. What is the probability that he stops at the the nth point.

Comment: You should look up the gambler's ruin problem, as this is just a version of it.

Comment: The answer is $1/(n-1)$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres You are right. I solved it.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn Thank you. I searched and I found my question is the simplest form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ ($1 \le X\le n$) be the start point that the man finally reaches the $n$-th point, so $\Pr(X=n)=1, \Pr(X=1)=0$.
For $X=k, 2\le k\le n-1$, we have a recursion formulation that \begin{align*}
    \Pr(X=k) = 0.5\Pr(X=k+1) + 0.5\Pr(X=k-1)\\
    \Pr(X=k + 1)-2\Pr(X=k)+\Pr(X=k-1) = 0
\end{align*}

Denote $Y = X-1$, so $0\le Y\le n-1$, thus the equation becomes\begin{equation*}
    \Pr(Y=k)-2\Pr(Y=k-1)+\Pr(Y=k-2) = 0,
\end{equation*}
which is a homogeneous linear recurrence with $\Pr(Y=0)=0, \Pr(Y=n-1)=1$ as the initialization. We first find its characteristic equation is\begin{equation*}
    x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0\implies x_1=1, x_2=1.
\end{equation*}
Then the solution is (according to [this book Chapter 10](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/eb5072ea046760bb81e5ce6bc1c97b37_MIT6_042JF10_chap20.pdf)) \begin{equation*}
    \Pr(Y=k)=a\times 1^k + kb\times 1^k.
\end{equation*}
By substition, we get\begin{align*}
    a &= 0;\\
    a + (n-1)b &= 1.
\end{align*}

So $\Pr(Y=k)=\frac{k}{n-1}$. Take $Pr(X=2)=Pr(Y=1)=\frac{1}{n-1}$.